# Xamarin forms toggle button default color on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How could I change the toggle button default color which is green on IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom Render for the switch ([UISwitch](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwitch/) in iOS) and set its [OnTintColor](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwitch.OnTintColor/) Property.

In PCL :

```
public class CustomSwitch : Switch
{
}
```

In iOS :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]

namespace xyz.iOS.CustomControlRenderers
{
    public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control != null) 
            {
                // do whatever you want to the UISwitch here!
                Control.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (204, 153, 255);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Since you don't need any customizations for android you need not create a custom render in the android platform.

You can get the list of all the native renders corresponding to Forms implementation from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/renderers/). 
An example of custom render can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with @Rohit answer, it will definitely work. However, I would like to point out that the better solution (for this particular case) would be to use Effects. [Why?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/introduction/#Why_Use_an_Effect_over_a_Custom_Renderer)

If you decide to go with it, your implementation could look something like this:

iOS project code:

```
using UIKit;
using VisualStimulation.iOS.Effects;
using VisualStimulation.Utilities;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(Constants.ResolutionGroupName)]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(SwitchEffects), nameof(SwitchEffects))]
namespace VisualStimulation.iOS.Effects
{
    public class SwitchEffects : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var switchControl = Control as UISwitch;
            if (switchControl != null)
            {
                switchControl.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(204, 153, 255);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnDetached()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Where `Constants.ResolutionGroupName` is just a string (e.g. "MyCompany"), defined in a separate class.

PCL code:

```
using VisualStimulation.Utilities;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace VisualStimulation.Effects
{
    public class SwitchEffects : RoutingEffect
    {
        public SwitchEffects() : base($"{Constants.ResolutionGroupName}.{nameof(SwitchEffects)}")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, XAML code:

```
<Switch>
    <Switch.Effects>
        <effects:SwitchEffects></effects:SwitchEffects>
    </Switch.Effects>
</Switch>
```

With `effect` namespace defined at the `ContentPage` level:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:<effect.class.namespace>;assembly=<nameOfYourAssembly>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it **app-wide** then the easiest way how to do it is in the **FinishedLaunching** method in the **AppDelegate.cs** file (in the iOS project):

```
UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00); // RED
```

Full example:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // switch
    UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
    // required Xamarin.Forms code
    Forms.Init ();
    LoadApplication (new App ());
    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
}
```

Source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/ios/theme/#UISwitch